# Adjusting a div based on the size of the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an HTML video player with Javascript generated controls(with background images of SVG graphics). I'm having an issue using the css `calc()` function, and need to resize the div's based on the video controls bar. So when the window is expanded/contracted, the controls need to adjust accordingly.

The controls div:

```
//Controls Wrapper
videoObj.controlsWrapper = document.createElement("div");
videoObj.controlsWrapper.className = "video-controls";
```

The controls are generated dynamically, so for instance, the play button is generated by this:

```
videoObj.playBtn = document.createElement("button");
videoObj.playBtn.className = "play btn";
```

So the question is how to adjust the size of the play button(which is a background of an SVG graphic), to a percentage(about 25%) of the height of the controls wrapper div.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/frrvxsyr/1/)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle example please?

Comment: Working on getting that setup. I'm essentially looking for a way to adjust one div based on a parent container. I know this can fairly easily be done with jquery, just not 100% sure on how.

Comment: I lll try a fiddle for you... hold on

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but i posted an example

Comment: Why not make the sizes a percentage in the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way... try resizing the box :)
The parent is relative. The child is absolute. Setting the top, left, right and bottom all to 0 will actually create a spider web effect ( or stretch effect ). I used different pixels so you could see the reaction. otherwise the child will cover the parent. Hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/m5wm1rLs/

```
.parent{

    position: relative;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.child{

    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 3px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

To test that this works, you can make parent resizable:

```
$('.parent').resizable();
```

Comment: resizable() is jquery ui specific method. OP asked for js or jquery solution. Resizeable doesn't make the contents resize based on container, it just adds a controller for users to manually resize element. It also doesn't appear to be mobile friendly. I see nothing in the docs indicating that it also resizes contents.

Comment: I just used resizable for demo only.

Comment: However it is triggered, the child will resize.

Comment: I edited your question to clarify that `resizable` is not actually the solution. You should consider updating your question to indicate what part of the CSS actually makes it work and why, as the answer originally reads like "here's some dummy html/css, here's a cool js method that makes the parent auto resize like you want."

Answer (score 0):

Resizing it to 25% of the parent `div` height is relatively easy, but only doable with a scripting language. As far as CSS has come by allow `calc()`, it has no support for pulling the sizes of designated elements.

Here's a simple script I threw together for you:

```
window.onload = function() {
    resize();
}

window.onresize = function() {
    resize();
}

function resize() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('play')[0].style.width = (document.getElementsByClassName('timeline')[0].offsetHeight * .25) + 'px';
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zq2vzkk5/

I recommend you use `id`s to identify the elements you want to pull the values from, but if the positions of the elements won't change on the page, then `class`es are fine. You just have to update which instance of the `class` you want to pull the value from if it does change.

If you want a jQuery variation, I can supply that, too.

I hope this helps.

**Edit**:

Here's the jQuery variation:

```
$(function() {
    resize();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        resize();
    });
});

function resize() {
    $('.play').first().width($('.timeline').first().outerHeight() * .25);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s51vrca2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without JS :

```
.play {
    height: 25%;
}
```